# Stability ODE's problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(0,0)$ is a equilibrium point of the System $(x,y)'=f(x,y)$, where $f(x,y)=(2xy-x^3, x^2-y^5)$ stable or unstable. I think that is unstable but i don't now how prove it. thanks for your skills

Answer (score 0):

My response is too long for a comment and is not intended to be a complete answer to your question. But here it goes.

The Jacobian of $f$ at the origin, namely $J_f(0,0)$, is the precisely zero matrix, and we can't use it to assess stability.  When this happens you'll want to refer to a directed graph of the vector field $$\vec{f}(x,y)=\Big<2xy-x^3,x^2-y^5\Big>$$ If you do so you'll see right that the critical point at the origin is unstable. You should also notice that $$(x,y)=\Big(\pm2^{5/8},2^{1/4}\Big)$$ are asymptotically stable critical points since the trace of $J_f$ is negative at both points. You may be able to identify a theorem which says any critical point wedged between two asymptotically stable critical points cannot itself be stable. I tried to find a theorem which made this claim myself but to no avail.

Comment: As there are no linear terms, the behavior close to the origin is dominated by the quadratic terms. There the system around the origin looks more like a saddle point, with the solutions following closely the level curves of $2y^2-x^2$.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I should point out though that saddle points are still categorized as unstable.